# User location doesn't print latitude/longitude

Tags: android, kotlin, location

Firstly, I want to check the location settings of the user:

```
fun checkSettings() {
    val builder = LocationSettingsRequest.Builder()

    val client: SettingsClient = LocationServices.getSettingsClient(this)
    val task: Task<LocationSettingsResponse> = client.checkLocationSettings(builder.build())

    task.addOnSuccessListener { locationSettingsResponse ->
        fusedLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(locationRequest, locationCallback, null)
    }

    task.addOnFailureListener { exception ->
        if (exception is ResolvableApiException){
             fusedLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(locationRequest, locationCallback, null)
            try {
                exception.startResolutionForResult(this@MainActivity, 500)
            } catch (sendEx: IntentSender.SendIntentException) {
                println("Error")
            }
        }
    }
```

I added this function in the `onCreate` method. If everything is fine, this other function in `onCreate` should print the latitude und longitude:

```
locationCallback = object : LocationCallback() {
        override fun onLocationResult(locationResult: LocationResult?) {
            locationResult ?: return
            for (location in locationResult.locations){
                println(location.latitude)
                println(location.longitude)
            }
        }
    }
```

But it doesn't work. I'm so sorry but I'm very confused and I have no idea what I should do. Any ideas?

Comment: You have add location permissions in the manifest and app settings allow using locations?

Comment: Are you getting any error messages?

Comment: yeah, of course @Barns

Comment: no, nothing. @JonahStarling

Comment: Is there a reason you are using `println()` over `Log.v()`? `println()` doesn't print to the android log while `Log.v()` does.

Comment: Even with `Log.v()` nothing happen

Comment: So, it works with the emulator, but not with a real device. Very confused...